# selenium to enter value in TextField or click on decrement arrow of sort increment and decrement button

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

selenium to enter value in TextField   or click on decrement arrow of sort increment and decrement button

**Problem Background :**
Using selenium webdriver with C#. Our application has UI with Sort Input box with increment and decrement button

I am able click in that text field which is inside  tag. And when we click in that test field increment and decrement sort button enabled

I have to enter value in that  tag field or I have click on decrement arrow button of sort

**Solution Tried:**
I have used correct xpath and i am able to click in that field but while performing sendkey operation getting element not interactible  exception

How can I enter value in td field or click on decrement arrow

Please refer attached UI
[image]

Comment: Can you please share HTML DOM for your elements (Above text box wih keys) and also what code you have tried till now ? It is a very vague way of asking **Is there any solution available  ?** .As the soluation will totally vary as per HTML DOM.

Comment: I can locate text field but arrow is enabled only when we click on text field. So when try to locate arrow then that becomes invisible hence difficult to inspect that

Answer (score 0):

probably you will need the selectors or xpath of the arrow buttons. Once you get the elements you can do the click()

Comment: We can not locate the xpath or selectors for that arrow button. When we click in that textbox only after that , those arrow becomes visible. So we can not inspect and locate for that arrow. When we click in that text field and mouse over on arrow button then we can see tooltip of that

Comment: then do a click on textbox first and wait for the arrow buttons to show. Not sure how to sleep the program in C# though but you can sleep the program for a second before finding the arrow buttons.

Comment: I have tried to sleep that as well. Problem is we can not locate xpath for that arrow as it becomes disabled once focus lost out of text field

Answer (score 0):

As your problem , looks like you are not able to identify coach for arrow. Do it in debug pause mode:

1. Open page in developer mode ( F12)
2. Go to textfield and click on it
3. Now go to Source tab
   4 ) Press F8
4. Now go to element tab and inspect your element as page is in debugger pause mode and you will not loose focus from text box for moving mode